# Update backbone model on click event and wait for response before changing location

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I would like to update a backbone model when a user clicks a link. The code I have at the moment is:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){

    // prevent default
    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $this.data('id');

    // update backbone model
    var click = new ClickModel({ "id": id });
    var response = click.save();

    // alert('testing');

    if(response.status = 200)
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

However, the database is not being updated before the url has changed. If I add in the alert it works. What is the best way of preventing the location change before the model save has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save):

> **save** `model.save([attributes], [options])`
>   [...]
>   **save** accepts `success` and `error` callbacks in the `options` hash, which are passed `(model, response, options)` and `(model, xhr, options)` as arguments, respectively.

So you can wait for the server to finish by saying:

```
click.save(null, {
    success: function(model) {
        // Do something interesting.
    }
});
```

Of course `save` is still an AJAX call so your "something interesting" will happen later. You can force the `save` to be synchronous but that's an evil thing to do your users so I won't show you how.

Comment: If I wanted the link to continue being loaded, would  I need to return false at the end of the "on" event function, and add `window.location.href = url` inside the success callback?

Comment: Yes, just make sure you grab the URL outside the `success` callback so that you have the right context. You might also want to add an `error` callback.